# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: hostname "smtp.gmail.com" does not match the server certificate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmail

This is what i have setup in setup_email.rb file,

```
if Rails.env.production?
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
      :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
      :port                 => "587",
      :domain               => "gmail.com",
      :user_name            => "username",
      :password             => "mypass",
      :authentication       => "login",
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
end
```

This code works in development and staging envoirnment.

This code was working fine on production, suddenly after several days it stopped working and i  am getting error message.
I have tried setting up `openssl_verify_mode: none` still does'nt work.

> Then i changed gmail account but getting same error. Seems like some
>   server side error

Error:

> OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: hostname "smtp.gmail.com" does not match the
>   server certificate

I have tried different methods out there on internet but its not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This stopped working today for us and we were able to fix with `openssl_verify_mode: none`

Comment: Please do not disabled openssl_verify_mode. Disabling this will send your emails to an unencrypted server or perhaps even to the wrong intended mail server.

Answer (score -1):

use

```
openssl_verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

or

```
openssl_verify_mode: 'none'
```

Answer (score -1):

In case this answer shows up for others, I had the same problem with a new Rails 7, Ruby 3.1 app.

In my instance, I send emails from the Rails app to a local Postfix instance which relays email to a commercial provider. Always worked fine for me for earlier apps.

My typical settings are:

```
 config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "localhost",
    port: 25,
    domain: "WHATEVERYOURDOMAINIS",
    enable_starttls_auto: false,
    openssl_verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
  }
```

This usually works fine, but with the current app, I kept getting errors like this:

```
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 peeraddr=127.0.0.1:25 state=error: certificate verify failed (Hostname mismatch) (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

Using the method to test mailers from this helpful post: **https://makandracards.com/makandra/52335-actionmailer-how-to-send-a-test-mail-directly-from-the-console** I find that using 0 or 'none' instead of OpenSSL::SSL:VERIFY_NONE does nothing, but it pointed me in the direction of the **net-protocol** gem, which also supports the **disable_start_tls** option.

I then adjusted my config to:

```
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "localhost",
    port: 25,
    domain: "WHATEVERYOURDOMAINIS",
    openssl_verify_mode: 'none',
    disable_start_tls: true,
  }
```

This gets rid of the problem in my case, though clearly it's disabling TLS completely so only useful if you're relaying mail like me through a local mailer.